# SAS: Count number of a particular type of disease with patient data on multiple lines

Tags: sas, frequency, medical

I have large dataset of a few million patient encounters that include a diagnosis, timestamp, patientID, and demographic information.

We have found that a particular type of disease is frequently comorbid with a common condition.

I would like to count the number of this type of disease that each patient has, and then create a histogram showing how many people have 1,2,3,4, etc. additional diseases.

This is the format of the data.

```
PatientID   Diagnosis   Date    Gender  Age
1           282.1       1/2/10      F   25
1           282.1       1/2/10      F   87
1           232.1       1/2/10      F   87
1           250.02      1/2/10      F   41
1           125.1       1/2/10      F   46
1           90.1        1/2/10      F   58
2           140         12/15/13    M   57
2           282.1       12/15/13    M   41
2           232.1       12/15/13    M   66
3           601.1       11/19/13    F   58
3           231.1       11/19/13    F   76
3           123.1       11/19/13    F   29
4           601.1       12/30/14    F   81
4           130.1       12/30/14    F   86
5           230.1       1/22/14     M   60
5           282.1       1/22/14     M   46
5           250.02      1/22/14     M   53
```

Generally, I was thinking of a DO loop, but I'm not sure where to start because there are duplicates in the dataset, like with patient 1 (282.1 is listed twice). I'm not sure how to account for that. Any thoughts?

Target diagnoses to count would be 282.1, 232.1, 250.02. In this example, patient 1 would have a count of 3, patient 2 would have 2, etc.

Edit:
This is what I have used, but the output is showing each PatientID on multiple lines in the output.

```
PROC SQL;
create table want as
select age, gender, patientID,
       count(distinct diagnosis_description) as count
   from dz_prev
   where diagnosis in (282.1, 232.1)
   group by patientID;
quit;
```

This is what the output table looks like. Why is this patientID showing up so many times?

```
Obs AGE GENDER PATIENTID count
1 55 Male 107828695 1
2 54 Male 107828695 1
3 54 Male 107828695 1
4 54 Male 107828695 1
5 54 Male 107828695 1
```

Comment: Post what you've tried.

Comment: You're next question is going to be which diseases and what the groups are so make sure your approach now considers that.

Comment: @Reeza I have updated the post to show what I tried and the result.

Comment: You are including variables (`age` and `gender`) that are neither group variables or aggregate statistics. Either add them to the GROUP BY or drop them from the list of selected variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you include variables that are neither grouping variables or summary statistics then SAS will happily re-merge your summary statistics back with all of the source records. That is why you are getting multiple records.  AGE can usually vary if your dataset covers many years. And GENDER can also vary if your data is messy.  So for a quick analysis you might try something like this.

```
create table want as
select patientID
     , min(age) as age_at_onset
     , min(gender) as gender
     , count(distinct diagnosis_description) as count
   from dz_prev
   where diagnosis in (282.1, 232.1)
   group by patientID
;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! How would I go about showing which people have 0 diagnoses that we are looking for?

Comment: You need to change the approach since then you cannot use the WHERE to eliminate the observations.  Instead move that inside the COUNT() function by using a CASE statement.  `count(distinct case when (diagnosis in (282.1,232.1)) then diagnosis_description end)`

Comment: PS You are going to get into trouble storing diagnosis codes in numeric variables. ICD10 codes all start with letters and there are also V and E codes in ICD9 that also start with letters.

Comment: I completely agree about storing the diagnosis codes as numeric variables. I did not include the ICD 10 codes in the sample data snippet, but they are there. What is the alternative you suggest?

Comment: It doesn't really impact the logic of this query, but store the codes as strings. So then your queries for specific values need to use use string literals instead of numeric literals.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can get what you want with an SQL statement

```
PROC SQL NOPRINT;
create table want as
select PatientID,
       count(distinct Diagnosis) as count
   from have
   where Diagnosis in (282.1, 232.1, 250.02)
   group by PatientID;
quit;
```

This filters to only the diagnoses you are interested in, counts the distinct times they are seen, by the PatientID, and saves the results to a new table.

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion! I have tried it, put it is giving me multiple lines of the same patientID in the output. I have updated the post above. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Kevin, the solution above works fine if you coded it as shown. If you use the age/gender as in your code it won't. Note that there's not a single word about age/gender in your question, so this answer is correct based on what you asked. And this is why it's important to show what you're doing.

Comment: based on your updated question, what Tom has will work.  The other option is to code that is shown and add the age and gender information on in a separate join.